# Difference between SyncML or JSON for synching

Tags: android, json, syncml

I wanted to sync contacts, calendar information from mobile devices to the server. Is SyncML the right choice to implement or one can go with JSON too? What is the difference between both these?

Comment: SyncML was horribly broken when it was designed back in 1999/2000, patched to "work" sort-of and marred with strange interop issues - usually caused by lazy vendors. There's no good reason to use this protocol unless you want to synchronize with old legacy devices or are selling a client to telecom company that has bought an expensive server it's unwilling to let go of (I've written some of those, and a few of the clients back when SyncML was still relevant).

Answer (score 1):

Synchronization Markup Language (SyncML) is standard format for sync datas with server. It's based on XML.

If you are going to use separate sync server like **Funambol**, which is using SyncML to synchronize contact and calender. then you have nothing to do with SyncML.

If you are going to sync contact information using your custom application, then json would be a good choice.

Comment: I would be doing a sync with a custom server application. I wanted to know the difference between syncml and json. Why SyncML is widely used for synchronization when json offers a lightweight solution.

Comment: @sunil json is a string representation of javascript object (Javascript Object Notation), you can easily convert javascript object to json and send to server where again that can be converted to java object for further processing, the domain is different from SyncML. SyncML designed for data synchronization (especially for reducing bandwidth consumption) also it's pretty less popular, and there is no point of comparing SyncML and json. what i think is developing application with json is more easy and maintainable, also u get more support in the communities, more library etc..